# How can I define a non-id primary key working in a Laravel database Migration?

Tags: php, sql, laravel, orm

I have a table where I'm going to save dates for a custom calendar. so I don't need an id pk. So how can I set the date as primary key using Eloquent (Laravel's ORM). I'd already read Laravel's Docs but I can't find a way for doing that. Is it possible? and how? If not, I'm going to use the unuseful id field.

I already tried something like this:

```
    public function up()
{
    Schema::create('t_calendarios', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->primary()->date('fecLab');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to add your 'fecLab' column, it should be unique:

```
$table->date('fecLab')->unique();
```

Then, you can set primary key like this:

```
$table->primary('fecLab');  //Add a primary key.
```

If you want to composite with other key:

```
$table->primary(['fecLab', 'id']);  //Add composite keys.
```

Ref: [Creating Index (Laravel Doc)](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/migrations#creating-indexes)

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following if you would like to set a custom key(s):

`$table->primary(array('key1', 'key2', 'key3'));`

Just specify your own keys that you would like to be primary and you should be set. Hope this helps!